# Select specific percentage of cells at random from numpy 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have foll. 2D numpy array:

```
array([[[-32768, -32768, -32768, ..., -32768, -32768, -32768],
        [-32768, -32768, -32768, ..., -32768, -32768, -32768],
        [-32768, -32768, -32768, ..., -32768, -32768, -32768],
        ..., 
        [-32768, -32768, -32768, ..., -32768, -32768, -32768],
        [-32768, -32768, -32768, ..., -32768, -32768, -32768],
        [-32768, -32768, -32768, ..., -32768, -32768, -32768]]], dtype=int16)
```

with following unique values:

```
array([-32768,    401,    402,    403,    404], dtype=int16)
```

Is there a way I can create a new array where 10% of the cells with 401 are changed to 500? I can use `np.random.random_sample()` to start but not how to select specified percentage of cells (e.g. 10% from this numpy 2D array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote your array by `a`. Then this will do the job:

```
locs=np.vstack(np.where(a==401)).T
n=len(locs)
changes_loc=np.random.permutation(locs)[:n//10]
a[changes_loc[:,0],changes_loc[:,1]]=500
```

Here is a small example (with different numbers and 25% instead of 10%, just to depict the behavior):

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,1,5],[1,1,7]])
locs=np.vstack(np.where(a==1)).T
n=len(locs)
changes_loc=np.random.permutation(locs)[:n//4]
a[changes_loc[:,0],changes_loc[:,1]]=70
```

the result is

```
array([[70,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  1,  5],
       [ 1,  1,  7]])
```

Comment: This was just a small example so you can see how it behaves. In your code you should do n//10 (as I wrote in the first part of my answer), since you want 10%.

Comment: thanks! and what does `a[changes_loc[:,0],changes_loc[:,1]]` do?

Comment: a[changes_loc[:,0],changes_loc[:,1]] acces to the locations specified by changes_loc in a (it would be more natural to just do a[changes_loc] but unfortunately it is not possible in numpy).